# Regex selecting every capital after a comma

Tags: .net, regex, powershell, powershell-4.0

Basically I'm trying to automate sending a email attached with a file by grabbing information from that file name to generate the email it will be sent to. I've searched across the site and haven't found something similar so I'm sorry if I am creating a repeated question. I'm attempting to do this in **Powershell 4.0**

The format of our emails are **firstinitialLASTNAME@company.com**
so for me it would be **jgetz@company.com**

**Where I'm Stuck : Regex**
I've created the expression `\b\w*(?=,)` which in the scenario of a file named
**Getz, Jacob 2017.9.4.pdf** 
will fetch the last name on powershell and regexstorm.net like I need to but the cheat sheets I am looking up are not really applying right when I try to get any capital after the comma (This is because some people have names like Jo-Ann). That's really where I need the help, I don't have full knowledge yet in scripting/automation to really google or research that specific of a topic.
Below is how I am fetching the last name I haven't gotten much farther as I just changed paths to structure the automation like this and I'm hung up at the step described.

```
$myFolder = 'C:\Users\jgetz\Desktop\Testfolder'

Foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem $myFolder)
{
  $myFile = $file.name
  $myFile2 = $myFile -Match "\b\w*(?=,)"
  $Matches.Values | Out-Host
}
```

Comment: What happens when you employ Julian Getz?  Will people start getting emails with documents intended for someone else?  Just something to think about...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by splitting the file name by `,`:

```
$filename = 'Getz, Jacob 2017.9.4.pdf'

# Split file name into two parts on first , 
$lastname,$rest = $filename -split ',',2
```

Now we've gotten the last name squared. Then use the `-creplace` operator (the `c` in front of `replace` means it's *case-sensitive*) to remove any non-uppercase character from the rest of the string:

```
$firstinitials = $rest -creplace '[^\p{Lu}]'
```

`\p{Lu}` is .NET regex for "all unicode **L**etters, **u**ppercase". `[^\p{Lu}]` negates it.

Now all you need to do is construct the mail address:

```
$mailaddress = "$firstinitials$lastname@company.com"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i appreciate you breaking it down so i can understand it better, as pointed out there will eventually be a flaw as capacity rises but its all an effort to get a starting point in learning and grasp as much as i can to get an understanding. per what James said i will manually do theirs in a seperate folder as it will be a long time til that scenario gets out of hand in this scale of a company

Comment: FYI `[^\p{Lu}]` = `\P{Lu}`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, had completely forgotten about `\P`